# Thread-Waiting Until File Modification

Tags: java, multithreading, file

I'm looking for a way to sleep a thread until a file is modified (as in the file is touched and/or changed) in Java 1.8.  Basically, this thread must read the contents of the file, be alert to any changes, but cannot absorb a core just for reading the file, waiting, read it again, waiting, etc.

Ideally, a thread would block in the same way that the concurrent blocking queue puts threads to sleep until there is something to be removed from the queue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [NIO `WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html):

> A watch service that watches registered objects for changes and events. For example a file manager may use a watch service to monitor a directory for changes so that it can update its display of the list of files when files are created or deleted.

To use it you need to:

```
// 1 create the watchService
WatchService watchService =    FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

// 2 get a reference to the directory to be watched for changes
String watchedDir = "/mydir";
Path dir = Paths.get(watchedDir);

// 3 register on the events you need to watch
WatchKey watchKey = dir.register(watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY);

...

// 4 wait for changes, generally inside a loop
watchKey = watchService.take();
```

The method take returns a watch key when available, otherwise waits.